# creating and managing cache and session in Zend Framwork 2

Tags: session, caching, config, zend-framework2

i just started working with ZF2 ... 
i want to initialize `cache` and `session` in config file and be able too use it in the application ( every where ) either using service manager or ... i have been searching Google for hours with no lock ... couldn't find anything useful in the documentations and ...

i tried this in module.config.php(Application module):

```
'service_manager' => array(
        'factories' => array(
            'cache' => '\Zend\Cache\StorageFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'cache' => array(
        'storage' => array(
            'adapter' => 'Filesystem',
            'options' => array(
                'cache_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../../data/cache'
            ),
        ),
        'plugins' => array('WriteControl', 'IgnoreUserAbort'),
        'options' => array(
            'removeOnFailure' => true,
            'exitOnAbort' => true,
            'ttl' => 100
        ),
    ),
```

i got this error : `While attempting to create cache(alias: cache) an invalid factory was registered for this instance type.`
so whats the valid factory ?
so any one can help me out here ?
tanks...

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Session is started automatically, you don't have to worry about it, if you want to change it, change it in php.ini

Comment: ???? where is my question says anything about how to start session?

Comment: "i want to initialize cache and session"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a closure as factory instead because `Zend\Cache\StorageFactory` doesn't implement `Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface`

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'cache' => function () {
            return Zend\Cache\StorageFactory::factory(array(
                'storage' => array(
                    'adapter' => 'Filesystem',
                    'options' => array(
                        'cache_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../../../data/cache',
                        'ttl' => 100
                    ),
                ),
                'plugins' => array(
                    'IgnoreUserAbort' => array(
                        'exitOnAbort' => true
                    ),
                ),
            ));
        },
    ),
)
```

Btw. clean up your cache configuration and where you get the plugin in `WriteControl` and the option `removeOnFailure` from?

Comment: i get WriteControl and removeOnFailure from zend documentation samples :D

Comment: It looks like you are using the original proposal - please read the official documentation instead - http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html#zend-cache

Answer (score 0):

I've come to this topic from Google with the same error name but definitely different reason. Error could be caused by file not found error. If you get this error, check your config record

```
'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
```

and be sure that needed file (mapper in my case) is located in the directory according to upper rules.